# Difficulties in making a chat app with node.js and socket.io

Tags: json, node.js, npm, chat, npm-install

I started to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNKNYLv2BpQ), where this programmer, shows step by step a very basic chat app.

My problems start when I'm trying to execute the "npm install" command. I get the following message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIwVN.jpg)

I am doing everything the same as in the video.

Comment: Ill try to post here "my code", but for some reason it comes out all in one line...

{
"name":"chat",
"version":"0.0.1",
"private":"true",
"dependencies:":{
 "socket.io":"1.4.4"
 "express":"4.13.4"


}

}

Comment: Do not include screen shots of text. Instead, copy and paste the text directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ "name":"chat",
  "version":"0.0.1",
  "private":"true",
  "dependencies:":{ 
     "socket.io":"1.4.4", 
      "express":"4.13.4" 
  } 
}
```

It is the comma after socket.io in dependencies that was missing. should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will probably bore you here to death with my stupid questions... :)

Comment: use npm install "ModuleName" --save option instead of editing package.json on your own... this will save you from the typos

Example : npm install express --save

Comment: Thanks for that. Now i came across another one.

var express = require ('express')
 app = express(),
 server = require ('http'),createServer(app),
 io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
 
 server.listen(3000);
 
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  )};

after i run the "node app.js" i get "unexpected token )"

i really do feel stupid for asking what i think are some really dumb questions...